# Making a fake wall to mount a tv, easy as it seems? will the fake studs be able to carry the same weight?

Tags: walls, mounting, studs, television

The fake wall is strictly aesthetics but there are 5 studs on the actual wall, then we will be attaching 5 more "studs" kinda [like this.](http://351685206.r.lightningbase-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/IMG_1028.jpg) But it will be from the floor to around 3/4th of the actual wall. Then put drywall/plasterboard on top of that. Will that fake wall be able to handle the weight of possibly 100-150 lbs? and the mount for the tv is stationary.

Most of the tutorials I've seen only had small screened tvs and for the most part did not include shelving.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the *fake studs* are mounted to the real studs, there should be no problem. We have been hanging mirrors weighing several hundreds of pounds by screwing into studs for hundreds of years.

It is important that your aesthetic wall is well anchored. Numerous screws into numerous studs. Then make sure your TV mount has several screws into the new studs. 3/8 or 1/4 inch lag screws are a good choice.

Comment: Yes, the fake studs will be mounted on the real ones. And thanks on the advice for lag screws, never would have thought of that!

Comment: And do drill the proper sized pilot hole for the lag bolts. If done correctly they will be way stronger that way than just trying to force them into the stud. If forced in the stud often splits a bit near the lag bolt and the threads only engage part of the way into two sides. With the pilot hole all the threads of the lag fully engage the wood.